# Check each listview attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview

I have listview such like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="listorder">
<li data-table='1'>menu a</li>
<li data-table='2'>menu b</li>
<li data-table='1'>menu c</li>
<li data-table='2'>menu d</li>
<li>spacer<li>
<li data-table='1'>menu e</li>
<li data-table='2'>menu f</li>
<li data-table='3'>menu g</li>
<li data-table='4'>menu h</li>
</ul>
```

I want to check all element in `listorder` and filter `listorder` that only display contain attribute `data-table='1'` and hide other `li`. First it will display all element, when user click a link table 1 from other link, it will filter `listorder`. when user click a link to display all, `listorder` will display all `li`, no filter.

how to do that in jquery?
Thank you all.

Thanks to @RGS my final code become:

```
$('#tabletab').off('tap', 'a').on('tap', 'a', function() { 
  tablepick = $(this).attr('data-table'); 
  $('ul#listorder > li').hide(); 
  if (tablepick=='0') $('ul#listorder > li').show(); 
  $('#listorder li').filter('[data-table="'+tablepick+'"]').show(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks to @RGS, my final code become: 
$('#tabletab').off('tap', 'a').on('tap', 'a', function() {
  tablepick = $(this).attr('data-table');
  $('ul#listorder > li').hide();
  if (tablepick=='0') $('ul#listorder > li').show();
  $('#listorder li').filter('[data-table="'+tablepick+'"]').show();
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.filter').click(function(){
$('ul#listorder > li').each(function(index){
    if($(this).data('table')==1){
        $(this).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
});
$('.link').click(function(){
    $('ul#listorder > li').show();
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/5c4tj/3/

Answer (score 0):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s3tvt/2/)

Try this,

```
$('#filter').click(function () {
    $('#listorder li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).data('table') !== 1) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

OR Just

```
$('#filter').click(function () {
    $('#listorder li').each(function(){
          $(this).toggle($(this).data('table') == 1);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s3tvt/3/)**

References :

**[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** - Alternative you can use **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**